# IP Camera Compatibilty on streaming using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, url, rtsp, ip-camera

Can anyone tell if this IP camera is capable of streaming in OpenCV.
I tried [this](http://skjm.com/icam/mjpeg.php) but still not working. I think the problem is to find the correct URL, I'm hoping you could find some solution on this problem.

Rover System: MODEL - RND-813HBKSCD
IP dome camera

This sample code from python 2.7/3 works fine in my laptop camera but when I try my IP camera it doesn't respond to it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0);

while(True):
    ret,img=cam.read();
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imshow("Face", img);
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

when I use this sample IP camera URL:

> cap =
>   cv2.VideoCapture("http://admin:admin12345@192.168.0.0/mjpg/video.mjpg")

It's get this.

> error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Romel II G. Albia\Surveillance_IPC\IPCNB\Snap\192.168.1.13\stream1.py", line 17, in 
>       main()
>     File "C:\Users\Romel II G. Albia\Surveillance_IPC\IPCNB\Snap\192.168.1.13\stream1.py", line 9, in main
>       cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
>   error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Comment: We can't offer any information about what your hardware supports or doesn't. Contact the camera manufacturer for that information. This site is for questions related to programming (code) or programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, version control systems, etc.), not hardware compatibility. See the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: Thank you sir, hope they can help my problem. @KenWhite

Comment: You missed my point. You have to edit your question to ask something else. *We can't offer any information about what your hardware supports or doesn't*. You need to ask a different question and remove the image. Hardware questions are off-topic here. (And even if they were on topic, the image would not be needed. You could have typed in the brand and model number, which would have been much easier to read and much nicer to people using mobile devices or screen readers.)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm new to this @KenWhite

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Much better. Your title still asks the wrong question. :-)

Comment: Also, read the error. The relevant line is *error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0*. It seems pretty clear that either `w` or `h` returned a negative value, which means there is an issue before the `for (x,y,w.h) in faces:` line.

Comment: could that error be the reason why my IP can't project stream? @KenWhite

Comment: Um, yes. It's a stop at either an assertion or an error that prevents the code from executing. The code clearly checks to make sure width and height are greater than zero, and if one of them is not it's throwing an error. You're seeing an error, so it's clear one of them (or both) is not greater than zero, and the `(-215)` is probably the value it's getting instead. What development environment are you using for your Python? Does it have a debugger? If so, step through the code starting at `for (x,y,w,h) in faces:` and inspect the values of `w` and `h`. If not, insert `print()` statements.

Comment: I'm using the IDLE(python gui) 
ok will do